# Função para calcular maior percentual de contratações por região em R

Tags: r, funções, data

Olá,
Estou tentando fazer uma função que retorne o maior percentual(Taxas_IN) de contratações em uma região(Local), sendo que a saída seria o setor(Atividade) e a respectiva taxa com maior percentual.
Eu consigo extrair o maior percentual mas eu não consigo extrair o setor correspondente.
Segue o código:

```
setor_maior_percentual_contratacoes_regiao <- function(df, regiao) {
  df_reg <- subset(df, Local == regiao)
  
  #calcula o vetor de setores da economia
  col_setores <- df_reg$Atividade
  setores <- col_setores[!duplicated(col_setores)]  # gera o vetor sem duplicação de valores

  #inicialmente considera o primeiro setor como o de maior percentual
  maior_taxa_in <- max(df_reg$Taxas_IN)
  setor_maior   <- setores[1]

  for(setor in setores){
    
    taxa_setor <- df_reg$Taxas_IN
    #verifica se o setor teve o maior percentual de contratações
    if(taxa_setor > maior_taxa_in){
      setor_maior <- df_reg$Atividade
      maior_taxa_in <- taxa_setor
    }
  }
  return(c(setor_maior, maior_taxa_in))
}
```

Quando aplico a função como em:

```
cat("\n Setor com maior número de contrataões na regiãoSul: 
     \n setor - percentual de contratações \n")
cat(result[1], " -- ", result[2])
```

Eu tenho como resultado `1 -- 7.7` mas deveria ser `B -- 7.7`, sendo B o setor correspondente ao valor 7.7 (maior percentual para o Sul, no caso do exemplo)
O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Bem-vinda ao StackOverflow em Português! Infelizmente, esta pergunta não pode ser reproduzida por quem for tentar respondê-la. Por favor, dê uma olhada [neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6700/como-fazer-uma-pergunta-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r/6701#6701) (principalmente no uso da função `dput`) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R. Assim, as pessoas que desejarem te ajudar conseguirão fazer isto da melhor maneira possível.

Comment: Pode, por favor, **editar a pergunta** com a saída de `dput(df)` ou, se a base for muito grande, de `dput(head(df, 20))`? (`df` é a base que é passada à função.)